# SQL and DateTime - How do I select all rows that have existed for a specific time period?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, timestamp

I have a table with a row named `time` of type `DATETIME`.

How can I select all rows which 'live' no more than 5 days?

Or in other words, how can I grab data which has timestamp not more then 5 days ago?

---

My request:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `stats` 
WHERE `domain` = 'test.com' AND DATEADD(NOW(), interval -5 day) > 'accept_date'
```

`accept_date` is the real name of a row. So , with that code I got:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') > 'accept_date' LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the RDBMS but in MySQL it would be

```
where date_add(now(), interval -5 day) > time
```

or

```
where datediff(now(), time) < 5
```

The first means "120 hours have passed since", the second means "5 calendar days have passed since".

`time` is a terrible column name, by the way.  Time of what?

Comment: `time` is just an example, in real case it hase another naming.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM `stats` WHERE `domain` = 'test.com' AND DATEADD(`accept_date`, INTERVAL 5 DAYS) > NOW()` throws an error near `DAYS) > NOW()`.

Comment: Sorry to sound picky, but generic variable names like `time`, `index`, and `amount` are the bane of my existence

Comment: Eek! `DAY` singular, not `DAYS`.  Fixed in answer.

Comment: Second tip doesn't work, I have, for example, such timestamps in DB: `2011-06-16 19:28:35`; `2011-07-16 19:27:19`. All of them are returned. `NOW()` is `2011-07-16 20:51:10`.

Comment: What does `SELECT datediff(now(), accept_time) FROM `stats` WHERE `domain` = 'test.com' AND datediff(now(), accept_time) < 5;` display?  Maybe you've got the order of the arguments reversed.

Answer (score 2):

`'accept_date'` is not the name of a column - it's a character literal.

You want

```
AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), interval -5 day) > accept_date
```

(note the missing single quotes `'` around the column name)

Comment: Same situation without quotes.

Comment: It's not `DATEADD`, it's `DATE_ADD` -- to avoid the lack of confusion that would be caused by spelling it like `DATEDIFF`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name -- Since it's your fault [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5otZg3Rui_M) is stuck in my head, I wish to inflict on you too.

Answer (score 0):

GETDATE() is DB specific, yet:

```
select * from TABLE where (GETDATE() - time) <= 5
```